# Win10 - Cloned disk to SSD - how do I identify which EFI system partition is in use?

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, boot-partition

I got a new Asus laptop with Win10 home. Installed a m.2 SATA ssd and cloned the original hdd to the ssd copying all partitions (and resizing the OS partition to the smaller SSD size). Then in the bios, set the SSD first in the boot order.

As of now, the system boots from the SSD and shows the OS partition on the SSD as active. But I'm not sure if it is in fact using the cloned EFI system partition (since I didn't do anything explicitly for that).
Disk manager shows both disks each with three partitions. I'd like to wipe the HDD and use it for other stuff - but I'd like to confirm that the EFI system partition that it came with isn't being used.

I guess one way is to just unplug the HDD from the system and check if it boots - but removing the HDD isn't an option since it's hard to get to on this laptop.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Instead of wiping the drive, just disconnect the drive, and see if the system will boot.  If it does boot then you are free to wipe the drive, if it does not boot, then you will have to provide us enough information for us to help you solve that problem.

Comment: That's the thing... Getting the back off is hard and I don't want to risk breaking the fiddly plastic clamps that snap shut

Comment: @Raghu Most systems allow enabling/disabling drives in UEFI.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - I checked and the Asus one doesn't. Just lists connected SATA drives :(